# Managed C++ or C# .NET, Downloading from rapidshare?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, download, rapidshare

I am trying to download a file from rapidshare via C++ .NET but I'm having a bit of trouble.

The address used to be  "https://ssl.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/premiumzone.cgi" but that no longer works, does anyone know what the new one is?
The code works but the file size is always 1KB, I don't think its connecting to the right server.

```
private: void downloadFileAsync(String^ fileUrl)
{
    String^ uriString;

    uriString = "https://ssl.rapidshare.com/premzone.html";//"https://ssl.rapidshare.com";

    NameValueCollection^ postvals = gcnew NameValueCollection();
    postvals->Add("login", "bob");
    postvals->Add("password", "12345");
    // postvals->Add("uselandingpage", "1");

    WebClient^ myWebClient = gcnew WebClient();
    array<unsigned char>^ responseArray = gcnew array<unsigned char>(10024);
    responseArray = myWebClient->UploadValues(uriString, "POST", postvals);

    StreamReader^ strRdr = gcnew StreamReader(gcnew MemoryStream(responseArray));

    String^ cookiestr = myWebClient->ResponseHeaders->Get("Set-Cookie");

    myWebClient->Headers->Add("Cookie", cookiestr);
    //myWebClient->DownloadFileCompleted += gcnew AsyncCompletedEventHandler(myWebClient->DownloadFileCompleted);

    myWebClient->DownloadFileAsync(gcnew Uri(fileUrl),"C:\\rapid\\"+Path::GetFileName(fileUrl));   
}


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    downloadFileAsync("http://rapidshare.com/files/440636806/ArcadeBackground.png");

}
```

Comment: What's the content of that 1kB file? I assume it's some kind of error that might help you

Comment: This language is called C++/CLI, not C++.NET and definitely not "Managed C++".  We use the last term only as shorthand for "Managed Extensions for C++" which was part of VS2002 and VS2003 and died a well-deserved death when C++/CLI came out in VS2005.

Answer (score 2):

Rapidshare has completely overhauled their structure lately. That 1kb file is probably HTML text telling you what you're doing wrong.

**Edit**

Are you using the [Rapishare API](http://images.rapidshare.com/apidoc.txt)? Because your code doesn't look at all like what I see on their documentation page.

Comment: well in the folder the file appears as ArcadeBackground.png but when i open it i get the pic is corrupted/ damaged error.

Comment: if i open it with notepad i get

<script type="text/javascript">location="/#!download|332l33|440636806|ArcadeBackground.png|535";</script>

Comment: So it's a javascript redirect, and some of the parameters in the new query string are probably time limited.  Looks like you'll have to download that first, parse the new URL, and make a second request.